# Generating data navigation automatically from GraphQL Schema

Tags: reactjs, rest, automation, graphql

I am trying to parse the Schema & AST of a given GraphQL endpoint in order to create auto-generated navigation (according to the parsed schema) for my data.

I tried looking for a solution for public projects but couldn't find any. If anyone has any suggestion / could refer me to a starting point it could be amazing.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "pages" in this context. Can you please elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish, perhaps with a more specific use case?

Comment: @DanielRearden Parse the Schema & AST of a given GraphQL endpoint, then create a sort of auto-generated navigation (automatically generated according to the parsed schema), that fetches and display the actual data (corresponding to the navigation of course).

Comment: I would start by looking at the code for both [GraphiQL](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql) and [GraphQL Playground](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-playground) -- both IDEs implement schema viewers that do something similar, allowing you to navigate through the various types.

Comment: Of course, those apps don't actually generate queries from the schema. That's a whole other can of worms, since you not only have to handle missing field arguments, some of which may be required, but also consider how to handle fields that have subselections and effectively decide how "deep" you want to go. This sort of thing is also has the potential for infinite recursion if you have any types that have circular references.

Comment: @DanielRearden, exactly, that's the reason I prefer using an existing library if any. I am familiar with parsing the Schema but I hoped that there are already projects doing that